# I want to add css to app-master-form-field using formControlName in angluar material. How can I add style?

Tags: angular-material-6, mat-form-field

I have use this
`<app-master-form-field [     label]= "'1 Min'"      [formControlName]="'min1'"      [ngClass]="{'has-error': formNewBorn.get('min1').invalid}"  </app-master-form-field>`
and CSS
`.has-error input {     border-color: red;  }`
but its not working. how can I style this input using formControlName?

I need any related solution to this problem.